# Cannot import name 'StandardScalar' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to import StandardScalar from Sklearn, preprocessing but it keeps giving me an error.

This is the exact error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1f73df509116> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScalar

ImportError: cannot import name 'StandardScalar' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (c:\users\abhijith rao\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScalar
```

Answer (score 16):

Mistyping

StandardScalar -> StandardScaler

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html