# How can i solve standart scaler import error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I can't import StandartScaler.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandartScaler
```

Error message

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6480\3084847266.py in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandartScaler

ImportError: cannot import name 'StandartScaler' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (C:\Users\EREN\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot import name 'StandardScalar' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526848/cannot-import-name-standardscalar-from-sklearn-preprocessing)

Comment: it's called `StandardScaler` with a `d`. A good first option is to look up the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Answer (score 2):

You wrote it wrong. Try `from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`. You wrote "Standart" instead of "Standard".